# Querying for SMS sent via Project Fi

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sms, google-project-fi

When an `SMS` is sent/received on a `Project Fi` Android phone using `Hangouts`/`Messenger` how is it stored?

When querying for messages using Android's [sms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html) or [mms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.html) `ContentProvider`s I'm only getting sms messages sent/received when the phone wasn't part of `Project Fi`.

Any way to query for those messages? Are those messages even stored on the same DB?

P.S.
I'm aware that [only Hangouts/Messenger are supported](https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6211316?hl=en) for sending/receiving:

> **On third-party apps**
>
> If you're using any app other than Messenger or Hangouts to send and
>   receive messages, download the most recent version of Messenger and
>   make it your default messaging app for best results.

I want to be able only to **query** for those messages sent via one of those apps.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this. The only time this ever comes up is when users are asking about missing messages. Hopefully somebody has some insight on this. Do you have a device on Project Fi, by chance, for testing?

Comment: @MikeM. no, same as you, i'm getting reports from users

Comment: Bummer. Yeah, I don't have one, either, otherwise I could do some testing. I've done some pretty extensive searches, but just can't find anything useful. Well, let's hope your question gets some bites.